# how to trace an existing ansible project

Tags: networking, automation, ansible, yaml

I am not very sure how to trace an existing project written in YAML for networking devices.
I have setup the system correctly and its executing all the tasks perfectly. But I want to check what all data are being assigned.

Is there a way to trace ansible just like python?

Ex: In python, I can use ipdb module or just use print() statement to see all kind of things.

Comment: Ansible playbooks are meant to be [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-idempotency) so you should be able to run the playbook again without anything changing. However, a safer option is to re-run it in check mode `-C` and with verbose printing on `-v` or `-vvv`. Diff more `-D` is also good when you are looking for changes.
`ansible-playbook -C -D -vv your_play.yml` would be the full command to get debug output.

Comment: Thanks micke. What if I want to check what's stored in a variable. Will debug be my only option?

Comment: As far as I know debug is the only option available to see the value stored in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible provides a [Playbook Debugger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html), which can be used to trace execution of tasks.

If you want to debug everything in a play, you can pass `debugger: always`

```
- name: some play
  hosts: all
  debugger: always
  tasks: ...
```

Then you can use `c` command to continue to the next task, `p task_vars` to see variables or `p result._result` to see the result.

Debugger can be used on a task or a role level too like this:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: dj-wasabi.zabbix-agent
      debugger: always
```

It helps to not to pollute your roles with `debug` tasks, while limiting the scope of debugging.

The other method is to use [debug module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html), which is similar to using print statements in python. You can use in your tasks like this:

```
# Example that prints the loopback address and gateway for each host
- debug:
    msg: System {{ inventory_hostname }} has uuid {{ ansible_product_uuid }}

- debug:
    msg: System {{ inventory_hostname }} has gateway {{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.gateway is defined

# Example that prints return information from the previous task
- shell: /usr/bin/uptime
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result
    verbosity: 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. I was exactly looking for this!